# Don't let to write a number greater than max attribute in input

Tags: javascript, html, web

```js
document.querySelector("#maca").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.target.value > this.getAttribute("max")) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="maca" placeholder="maca" id="maca" max="7">
```

I'm trying to stop the user from entering a number greater than the value of the max attribute. What is happening is that first the user is allowed to write a larger number then not.

How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trickier than it looks, because even `<input type="number" max="7"/>` allows you to input `9` without complaining (I believe it *should* complain and block the input, but for some reason does not). Example below

```html
<input type="number" max="7"/>
```

I came up with this little JS solution :

```js
const max = +maca.getAttribute("max");

maca.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  const typed = +e.key;
  
  if(!isNaN(typed)) e.preventDefault(); // Allow any non-number keys (backspace etc.)
  
  if ( +(e.target.value + typed) <= max) {
    maca.value += typed
  } else {
    console.log(`Number too big! Max is ${max}`)
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" name="maca" placeholder="maca" id="maca" max="7">
```

This really won't allow the user to type `8` or `9`. Also, you can type `1` but then you can't add another digit to type `11`.

Comment: "I believe it should complain and block the input, but for some reason does not", It doesn't block input, but it fails a validation constraint so you can apply a custom style to the field to *inform*  the user that the value is invalid and let them correct it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/max

Comment: @JeremyThille: I did ;)

Comment: Indeed. In other words it's very loose, and not aggressively blocking any value that exceeds the maximum. It's mainly informative